# hide web part menu (checkbox and down arrow)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, web-part, css

Is there a way to hide the web part selection (see attached pic). I was trying to use CSS but for some reason, I couldn't. using sp 2013

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Most easy way: Edit web part properties and set **Chrome type: None** and top of the web part **insert content editor web part** in that write html code and display the header for the <h1>below web part</h1>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to hide it for the specific web part, so you should get the **ID** of this web part using `F12 (Developer Tools)`

In the below example, my web part ID was `SelectionCbxWebPartWPQ3`

```
<style>
#SelectionCbxWebPartWPQ3
{
  display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

If you need to hide the checkbox for all web parts within the page, use the below CSS

```
<style>
.ms-cursorDefault
{
  display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

> **Note:** add the above CSS style in Script Editor Web Part in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the specific web part selection, modify the "title" in CSS below to your web part title(In my test, the web part title is "Announcements"), and add the css into script editor web part in the same web part page.

```
<style type='text/css'>
.ms-webpart-chrome-title > span[title='Announcements'] + span.ms-webpart-controlBox{
    display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

[image]
If you want to hide all web parts selection, we can use the CSS below.

```
<style type='text/css'>
span.ms-webpart-controlBox{
    display:none !important;
}
</style>
```